# How to save video from usb webcam in Raspberry Pi by simulink?

Tags: pi-2, simulink

I had connected the usb webcam to Raspberry Pi.
I loaded the Simulink model that mention below onto Raspberry Pi board from the computer in external mode,

It give this message "could not open library: tommfile.dll".

I want to save and record this video in SD card of Raspberry Pi.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "by Simulink model" please? I can tell you how to grab a frame, invert it and save it, but I find the wording of your question, and the diagram which seems to be about something slightly different, confusing.

Comment: I modified the question.

Comment: I loaded the Simulink model that mention in the the question onto Raspberry Pi board, and the model ran normally from the computer in external mode, and the video was displayed.. I want to save and record this video in SD card of Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using Matlab.  Go in and make sure the support package you're using is the latest available. I'd recommend going directly to Mathwork's support community rather than here as it doesn't appear there are many familiar with Matlab and Simulink, and it could well be a bug that the support package maintainer needs to fix.

For others wondering what Simulink is.  It's a high end control system and programming environment used in aerospace and other markets requiring modeled and tested systems that can generate safety certified code.  JPL, and NASA are heavy users as well as the defense industry among others.  It's very expensive outside of student and crippled home editions, about $20k USD to do what he's doing with a commercial license, so unless you're heavily into math, engineering, or high-integrity control systems it's unlikely that you'll encounter it, but you probably frequently rely on things that run the code it's generated or helped design.